# Jquery check if a div is empty omitting: before or: after

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to check with Jquery if a Div is empty omitting: before or: after, doing this with a div that has a: before or: after takes into account the: before or: after

```js
$(function(){
  if($('#content').not(':empty')) {
    console.log('Yes content');
  } else {    
    console.log('No content');
  }
});
```

```css
#content:empty {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    text-align: center;
}

#content:empty:before {
    content: 'NO IMAGE';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Works [just as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/pfa4vct7/1/) for me? jQuery has no access to pseudo elements like `:before` ?

Comment: I am trying to detect if the DIV #content has some other content inside, and whenever I ask with Jquery if it is not empty it shows me that it is and has no content.

Comment: That's because it has no content? `:before` doesn't count as content, it's **before** the actual element ?

Comment: The before use it when the DIV is empty using CSS but in Jquery it does not seem to work in the same way as CSS

Comment: Probably not, `:empty` in jQuery doesn't neccessarely do the same as `:empty` in CSS, and again, javascript has **no** access to pseudo elements at all.

Comment: Understood, then I'll take the solution from @Samuel Cook, I do not use .not()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for HTML or text using the following:

```js
$(function(){
  if( $('#content').html() || $('#content').text() ){
    console.log('Yes content');
  } else {    
    console.log('No content');
  }
});
```

```css
#content:empty {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    text-align: center;
}

#content:empty:before {
    content: 'NO IMAGE';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Examples:

Empty:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

With text:

```
<div id="content">Hello World</div>
```

With HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <span class="child"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't this do exactly the same as the code the OP is using?

Comment: The before I use it when the DIV is empty using CSS but in @ Samuel Cook, I can use the sign! In Jquery, example, if( !$('#content').html() || !$('#content').text() ){}); am interested in giving priority to validate if the DIV is not empty Jquery does not seem to work in the same way as CSS

Comment: @adeneo you'd think it would, but checking for physical html or text seems to do the trick over the pseudo :empty condition.

Comment: Well okay, then something is broken, as jQuery `:empty` should select all elements that has no children (including text nodes), which would be the same as checking for text or html inside the element